# Databricks SQL issue mismatched input ')' expecting ','

Tags: sql, databricks

I am trying to solve the issue mismatched input ')' expecting ',', but cannot guess, what went wrong.
I have read all documentation, cannot find where I am missing the comma, becasue databricks says "Error in SQL statement: ParseException:
mismatched input ')' expecting ','(line 2, pos 108)":

```
 select 
 (CASE WHEN (fdse.`eventaction` IN ('zoom image')) THEN sum(CAST(fdse.`totalevents` AS 
 BIGINT)) END AS `zoom`)

 from GA_FAVORITES_DIGITAL_STYLIST_EVENTS as fdse
 inner join GA_FAVORITES_SESSIONS as fs
 on fdse.uniquesessionid = fs.uniquesessionid
 and fdse.trans_date = fs.trans_date
 where fs.trans_date >= date_add(current_date,-10)
 limit 10
```

UPD I fixed the mismatch error, but now I am having AnalysisException: grouping expressions sequence is empty, and 'fdse.`eventaction`' is not an aggregate function. Wrap '(CASE WHEN (fdse.`eventaction` IN ('zoom image')) THEN sum(CAST(fdse.`totalevents` AS BIGINT)) END AS `zoom`)' in windowing function(s) or wrap 'fdse.`eventaction`' in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get. PLease let me know how to fix that, because if adding the parentises again it will give me again the mismatch error.

Comment: Why so many parentheses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be because the `AS` is inside of the parentheses. Try this and let me know if it works:

```sql
SELECT
(CASE WHEN (fdse.`eventaction` IN 'zoom image') THEN SUM(CAST(fdse.`totalevents` AS BIGINT)) END) AS `zoom`
FROM GA_FAVORITES_DIGITAL_STYLIST_EVENTS AS fdse
INNER JOIN GA_FAVORITES_SESSIONS AS fs
ON fdse.uniquesessionid = fs.uniquesessionid
AND fdse.trans_date = fs.trans_date
WHERE fs.trans_date >= date_add(current_date, -10)
LIMIT 10
```

Sometimes SQL errors can be misleading!

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it says no viable alternative at input. As far as I got it happens when we type a character that doesn't fit in the context of that line.